# Identifying the controlling picklist of a dependent picklist

Tags: apex, dependent-picklist, describefieldresult

Is it possible to identify the controlling picklist for a dependent picklist in Apex. Currently, I am using the [DescribeFieldResult class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm) to get information on object fields; type, name, length, etc. In this class, there is a method that I am using to identify if a picklist is independent or dependent, isDependentPicklist(). Now, from here, I need to identify the controlling picklist
of the dependent picklist but I have had no success in finding a solution. Is what I am attempting even possible?

Comment: Have you got solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the `getController()` method of the `DescribeFieldResult` class that you linked to does just what you want.

It returns a `Schema.SObjectField` instance, which you can call `getDescribe()` on to get more information like the label, api name, etc...

For the dependent picklist `Application__c`, controlled by `Type` on the `Case` object in my org, the following returns "Type"

```
System.debug(Case.field.Application__c.getDescribe().getController().getDescribe().getName());
```